# not able to display inner child nodes value in recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

before down voting please consider this i have searched everywhere and not found the solution please help..

[image: Structure of Firebase]

from the above structure i want to access the values inside Results -> examId> total_marks, marks_scored but i am not being able to get inside Result node

i want the values to be feed inside recyclerview 
This is my adapter

```
public class MarksListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarksListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<MarksList> marksListArrayList;


    public MarksListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<MarksList> p) {
        context = c;
        marksListArrayList = p;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.marks_list, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.tvStudentName.setText(marksListArrayList.get(i).getName());
        myViewHolder.tvOutOf_List.setText(marksListArrayList.get(i).getResults().getTotal_marks());
        myViewHolder.etEnterMarks.setText(marksListArrayList.get(i).getResults().getMarks_scored());
```

POJO class

```
public class MarksList {
    String name;

    public MarksList() {
    }

    public MarksList(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    private Results Results;

    public com.hitech.hitechacademy.POJO.Results getResults() {
        return Results;
    }
}

public class Results {

    String marks_scored;
    String total_marks;

    public Results() {
    }

    public Results(String marks_scored, String total_marks) {

        this.marks_scored = marks_scored;
        this.total_marks = total_marks;
    }

    public String getMarks_scored() {
        return marks_scored;
    }

    public void setMarks_scored(String marks_scored) {
        this.marks_scored = marks_scored;
    }

    public String getTotal_marks() {
        return total_marks;
    }

    public void setTotal_marks(String total_marks) {
        this.total_marks = total_marks;
    }

}
```

both are seperate java classes

This is the recyclerview activity

```
DatabaseReference examRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Batches").child(batchNameValue);

examRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String examTitle;
        String studentName;

        specificStudent.clear();
        resultsArrayList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot studentResult : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            examTitle = (String) studentResult.child("Results").child(examKeyValue).child("exam_name").getValue();
            Log.d("TAG_Full", examTitle + "" + examFullName);
            if (examTitle != null && examTitle.equals(examFullName)) {

                MarksList marksList = studentResult.getValue(MarksList.class);


                //studentName = (String) studentResult.child("name").getValue();
                specificStudent.add(marksList);

                Log.d("SpecificStudent", specificStudent.toString() + resultsArrayList.toString());
            } else {
                //code for 1 exam and no students
            }
        }
        specificStudent.toString();
        marksListAdapter = new MarksListAdapter(LoadedExam.this,specificStudent);
        marksRecyclerView.setAdapter(marksListAdapter);
        marksListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I am not getting any errors but only the name of the student is getting fetched Please help

Comment: At a glance this seems wrong: `MarksList marksList = studentResult.getValue(MarksList.class);` You probably want to read from the correct child node: `MarksList marksList = studentResult.child("Results").child(examKeyValue).getValue(MarksList.class);`. If that doesn't solve the problem, put a breakpoint in `onDataChange` and check what exact line doesn't do what you expect it to do. It'll be much easier to help if we can focus on just the code that is causing the problem. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So how would i be able to retrieve the name of the student since in Results node only marks scored and total are available?